# How to get Node Coordinates Data in Sankey Graph

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I'm trying to create something similar to the image below. Where each column has a heading with it.

I know that chart.renderer.text can be used to create & place custom text on chart. However, I'm unable to find a way to fetch the column/node coordinates data(x,y) which would help me place them.

Also is there a programmatic way to do this task. For example, a function that fetches all the columns coordinates and populates all the headings from an existing list.

To summarize:

- How to fetch a columns (x,y) Coordinates?
- How to dynamically place headings for all columns from a list?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1qjb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the required coordinates and place the headers in `render` event, for example:

```
events: {
  render: function() {
    var chart = this,
      series = chart.series[0],
      columns = series.nodeColumns,
      isFirst,
      isLast,
      xPos;

    if (!series.customHeaders) {
      series.customHeaders = [];
    }

    columns.forEach(function(column, i) {
      xPos = column[0].nodeX + chart.plotLeft;
      isFirst = i === 0;
      isLast = i === columns.length - 1;

      if (!series.customHeaders[i]) {
        series.customHeaders.push(
          chart.renderer.text(
            headers[i],
            xPos,
            80
          ).attr({
            translateX: isFirst ? 0 : (
              isLast ?
              series.options.nodeWidth :
              series.options.nodeWidth / 2
            ),
            align: isFirst ? 'left' : (
              isLast ? 'right' : 'center'
            )
          }).add()
        )
      } else {
        series.customHeaders[i].attr({
          x: xPos
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6Lvdufbp/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Comment: Works perfectly! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for the effort & quick response!